# Best practice when not needed to render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit new in React, so my question is regarding a best practice on something i'm trying to do. I might not being "thinking react" so I need your help.

I'm involved with a really big project related to sports. To minimise the number of components I need to create, I'm trying to use one single component to deal with multiple sports.

I will try to draw a basic scenario where it will match with a similar thing i'm trying to do.

```
-----------------------------------
|  module: Scoreboard             |
|                                 |
|  -----------------------------  |
|  | module: scores            |  |
|  |   Sydney 1 x 0 Melbourne  |  |
|  -----------------------------  |
|                                 |
|  -----------------------------  |
|  | module: results           |  |
|  -----------------------------  |
|                                 |
|  -----------------------------  |
|  | module: Footer            |  |
|  -----------------------------  |
|                                 |
-----------------------------------
```

With this scenario in mind, mind that all the props gets loaded when the component is loaded or through a parent.

I have 2 things that i need to do here on my script.

1 - Only display the component **footer** if there is a footer which is represented by this.props.footer
2 - Only display the component **results** if there is results which is represented by this.props.results

Right now i have a few user cases that I can do here.

### User Cases (PARENT CONTROL)

On my ***render*** method I can do something like (don't mind the {...this.props} i only put there to represent i'm passing variables)

**Case 1:**

```
render: function() {
    var results, footer;

    if (this.props.results) {
        results = (<results {...this.props} />)
    }

    if (this.props.footer) {
        results = (<footer {...this.props} />)
    }

    return (
       <div class="scoreboard">
           <scores {...this.props} />
           {results}
           {footer}
       </div>
    );
}
```

The downside I see here is the amount of ifs inside the render. Not very readable, specially if we have a bit more than 2 components that does the same thing

**Case 2:**

```
render: function() {
    return (
       <div class="scoreboard">
           <scores {...this.props} />
           {this.props.results ? <results {...this.props} /> : ''}
           {this.props.footer ? <footer {...this.props} /> : ''}
       </div>
    );
}
```

Although I like this case better, Sometimes I have components that takes a big number of properties which can get to the same problem above (readability). Bare in mind i'm using {...this.props} to simplify the example

### User Cases (CHILD CONTROL)

Which is the case I like better. Putting all the logic inside it's own component.

The problem is that I don't know how to stop the first render. And I also don't want to put a "display: block" on the page avoiding to add unnecessary markup where is not needed, so my idea here is really do not render the component at all if it's not needed. 
If i'm doing it wrong, or this is an anti-pattern, i would like some insight of it, like i said, i'm new with all of this react stuff, any comment is welcome.

So basically, like I said, I can't stop it from rendering.

Lets take the results component for instance, and lets there is a table and there is about about 10 lines of markup in it. Let's draw a case:

On my ***render*** method I can do something like

```
module: SCOREBOARD 

render: function() {
    return (
       <div class="scoreboard">
           <scores {...this.props} />
           <results {...this.props} isVisible={this.props.results} />
           <footer {...this.props} isVisible={this.props.footer}  />
       </div>
    );
}

module: RESULTS

render: function() {
    return this.props.isVisible ? (
       <div class="results">
             <table>
                ....
             </table>
       </div>
    ) : null;
}
```

I would control the return of the render with a property isVisible. Defaulting it to always false. Haven't found a good article about it, but i'm assuming this is not an elegant way.

I know we have a shouldComponentUpdate, but this won't stop the first render on the page, which will display some of the tables in our examples.

I wonder if anyone has some insight, a valid argument, or a solution to do what I'm trying to do. Remember that It's a big project, so I'm trying to avoid to create hundreds of components and instead having to use one component where there are a few variables that I could or not display the component on the page.

Comment: I always use case 2. I use JSnoX, so adding simple js ternary operator among js code (no xml) doesn't look messy. For me it looks as it should look like. Also sometimes I use `!!this.props.results && results()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have this:

```
render: function() {
    return (
       <div class="scoreboard">
           <scores {...this.props} />
           {this.props.results ? <results {...this.props} /> : ''}
           {this.props.footer ? <footer {...this.props} /> : ''}
       </div>
    );
}
```

You can rewrite it as different methods:

```
render: function() {
    return (
       <div class="scoreboard">
           <scores {...this.props} />
           {this.props.results ? this.renderResults() : ''}
           {this.props.footer ? this.renderFooter() : ''}
       </div>
    );
},
renderResults(){
    return (
        <results {...this.props} />
    );
},
renderFooter(){
    return (
        <footer {...this.props} />
    );
},
```

This way the conditional part never gets larger with more props, but
you can still have that sub-render with the full thing.

---

> To minimise the number of components I need to create, I'm trying to use one single component to deal with multiple sports

Having a lot of components isn't bad. You can have a lot of tiny components. When deciding the boundaries think about these (in terms of requirements changing tomorrow).

For siblings (multiple components with similar api, not nested):

- will I need to update these components all at once? merge

  - example: a primary button is something you want to change once and have it affect everything
- will I need to have differences between these components? split

  - example: the score board may have significant display differences

For parent/child:

- does splitting make testing easier? split

  - example. list of inputs, testing events for one input is simpler than testing a list of inputs
- does it reduce the complexity by splitting? split
- does splitting result it pointlessly tiny components? merge

> avoiding to add unnecessary markup

Having unnecessary markup is something that happens often in react. It's a tradeoff, but doesn't usually cause problems.

> I would control the return of the render with a property isVisible

This is an anti-pattern. Unless you did this in every component, you're making assumptions about the user of the component which makes your code less modular and more difficult to maintain. Do conditional rendering in the parent unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it lines up with the way i think.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way;

```
    module: RESULTS

    render: function() {
        if (this.props.hide) return null;
        return (
             <div class="results">
                         <table>
                                ....
                         </table>
             </div>
        );
    }
```

Its a good pattern for clarity and performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing u want to do is not show, the footer and results when they are visible, go for solution one. Even though solution 2 is shorter, solution one is still better for readability,

it seems like ur looking for a way, to remove if statements ,in order to reduce code though as u can see in solution three, it just leads to code complexity.

I don't know what other props u are passing to the footer / results, but for this specific case, the if statement is the best way to go.

```
    [shouldComponentUpdate]
    Invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate is used. (facebook docs)
```

-U can use this to for example do a (shallow) compare between the old and new props, and return
true, when to render and false when not to render, (but this will only be triggered on update), 
its has to has old values first (as u described)

```
    [componentWillReceiveProps]
    invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.
    Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState() within this function will not trigger an additional render. (facebook)
```

-U could do some magic, here when the component receives props, u could decide to do 
this.setState({ isVisible: false });  and then in your render check for isVisible: false, and don't show its content, and later update this state. But you don't want to have "state" living in your components

you could also just pass a prop to the component, component visible={false}  and 
then check for this.props.visible , within the subcomponent, but u are just moving the if statements

But this is not the way it is supposed to work, the idea of the unidirectional data flow (top down)
with the react lifecycle is that a change is triggered from above, u should not stop the render,
if props is passed to its child component its should re-render -> if u wish to stop the render, u should do it in shouldcomponent update only if the data did not change, (take a look at immutable js (and purerender)) ,

But for this case just use the if statement.

I also would like to suggest for you to take a look at higher level components,
http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/05/02/react/ (also read the mixis are dead, long live composition link within it)

Answer (score 0):

The React documentation [has a whole page on conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).  If you are looking for best practice, I would start there.  For short and single-line elements, I personally like the terseness of [using the logical && operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).  It would look a lot like your Case 2:

```
render: function() {
    return (
       <div class="scoreboard">
           <scores {...this.props} />
           {this.props.results && <results {...this.props} />}
           {this.props.footer && <footer {...this.props} />}
       </div>
    );
}
```